# Why does my IsMouseOver event only work if my CheckBox is true?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a DataGrid in which I can change the respective colors when my CheckBox is activated. However, my IsMouseOver event only works if my CheckBox is true. As soon as my CheckBox is set to false, my IsMouseOver Effect no longer works, why? Do I have to set a trigger somewhere?

My Code from my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserResizeRows="True" GridLinesVisibility="None"
                  ColumnWidth="*" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                  Background="#222831" Foreground="White" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="Copy"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>


    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <!--Design kopfzeile-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Name="test" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Border x:Name="insideHeader" Background="#242A36">
                            <Border x:Name="borderHeader" BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="6"
                                Background="#2D2D30"
                                Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                Margin="2">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="#4182C6"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=toogleButton,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="#FA9F34"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2B2B2B"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="insideHeader" Property="Background" Value="#00336E"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
                           
        <!--Deaktivieren Des rowheader-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>

        <!--Cellen Design-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border x:Name="insideBorder" Background="#242A36">
                            <Border x:Name="BorderCell" BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="6"
                                Background="#292F3B"
                                Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                Margin="2">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="BorderCell" Property="Background" Value="#4182C6"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=toogleButton,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="BorderCell" Property="Background" Value="#0051B0"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="insideBorder" Property="Background" Value="#00336E"/>

                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>


        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change triggers' order. they both set Background. at the moment DataTrigger for IsChecked=false overrides Trigger for IsMouseOver=true, when CheckBox is unchecked, because DataTrigger is applied last.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=toogleButton,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="#FA9F34"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2B2B2B"/>
    <Setter TargetName="insideHeader" Property="Background" Value="#00336E"/>
</DataTrigger>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="#4182C6"/>
</Trigger>
```